# Distance function for sqlite

Tags: ios, c, sqlite, user-defined-functions

I am developing an iOS app in xcode 4.6.3. In this,i have an sqlite database with a table that contains latitude and longitude of various locations in degrees.I want to perform a select query in DB with the use of custom sqlite function which returns rows ordered by their distance from a given location and show them in my app's table view.  http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=71 , THIS LINK HAS THE EXACT SOLUTION I WANT BUT THE FOLLOWING FUNCTION

```
    static void distanceFunc(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv)
    {....}
```

NEVER GETS CALLED BY

```
sqlite3_create_function(sqliteDatabasePtr, "distance", 4, SQLITE_UTF8, NULL, &distanceFunc, NULL, 
NULL);
```

I have searched for weeks and most answers direct me to the above mentioned link but i cannot make it work.I have followed the exact same steps,even copied the same code but its not working for me.Whereas, Normal sql queries are working fine.What am i missing? please help.

Comment: Update your question with the code that performs your query using the `distance` function.

Comment: FYI - The `sqlite3_create_function` does not actually call your `distanceFunc`. It simply registers the function. You need an actual query that uses the `distance(v1,v2,v3,v4)` function.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks.Your reply made me think from a different perspective.The codes i've written works fine.It was so stupid of me.Actually the thing was i thought sqlite3_create_function would create a function in database (like creating functions or stored procedures in MsSQL), i built the project and executed my sql query "select * from tbl order by distance(Latitude, Longitude, 22.2,33.3)" in sqlite database browser which gave me error message "no such function:distance" but i never bothered to check if my query was returning rows in my project. Executing query in db browser was wrong approach.